# Finding an example of a bijection from $\Bbb N$ to $E^+$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

> Give an example of a bijection $h$ from $\Bbb N$ to $E^+$ such that $h(1) = 16, h(2) =12, \text{ and } h(3) = 2. $
>   $\Bbb N = \text{ natural numbers }$ , $E^+= \text{ positive even integers. }$

So in order to solve this problem we must find a one to one correspondence. Where each element of 1 set is paired exactly 1 element of the other.

$f: \Bbb N \rightarrow E^+,
\begin{cases}
16,  & \text{n} = 1 \\
12    & \text{n}=2 \\
2    & \text{n}=3 \\
\color{red}4    & \color{red}{ n=8} \\
\color{red}{6}    & \color{red}{\text{n}=6} \\
\color{red}{2n}   &\color{red}{\text{n} \neq 1,2,3,6,8}  \\
\end{cases}$

My question for this problem is how does someone derive everything after $2$ if $n =3$ ?  My guess is that one looks at all the even positive elements between $2$ and $16$ and list the ones that was not displayed. If that is the case how does one get $n$? Also the definition of an even number is $2n$.

Comment: Did you get the answer from another source, and are wondering how it was obtained?  Or did you obtain the answer yourself, and are wondering how to generalize the process?  Or something else entirely?

Comment: Yes I did , I just wondering how to generalize the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many correct answers; the one in the question is designed to make $f$ follow a simple formula as much as possible. One could also follow your suggestion of first taking care of the missing even numbers between $2$ and $16$, but this time just doing so in order:

$$\begin{array}{rcc}
n:&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&\ldots&n&&\\
f(n):&\color{blue}{16}&\color{blue}{12}&\color{blue}2&4&6&8&10&14&\color{red}{18}&\color{red}{20}&\ldots&\color{red}{2n}
\end{array}$$

Here the blue values are those that we were given, the black are the missing ones between $2$ and $16$, and the red are ones after that taking in their natural order. This function is

$$f(n)=\begin{cases}
16,&\text{if }n=1\\
12,&\text{if }n=2\\
2,&\text{if }n=3\\
4,&\text{if }n=4\\
6,&\text{if }n=5\\
8,&\text{if }n=6\\
10,&\text{if }n=7\\
14,&\text{if }n=8\\
2n,&\text{if }n\ge 9\;.
\end{cases}$$

If you look closely, you’ll see that it could equally well be written

$$f(n)=\begin{cases}
16,&\text{if }n=1\\
12,&\text{if }n=2\\
2n-4,&\text{if }3\le n\le 7\\
14,&\text{if }n=8\\
2n,&\text{if }n\ge 9\;.
\end{cases}$$

The version in your question was chosen to maximize the set of $n$ for which $f(n)=2n$.

Comment: I understand your answer perfectly. Yet the only thing I do not understand is why is that in your answer. $ 14  \text{ if } n = 8,$ . Yet in mine it says $4 \text{ if } n =8 $? Would your answer be as correct as my  answer?

Comment: @LittleJon: Both are equally correct, and there are infinitely many other correct answers. The idea in yours is to make $f(n)=2n$ as much as possible, so it makes $f(4)=8$. It can’t make $f(8)=16$, since $16$ is already $f(1)$, and it can’t get $4$ as $f(2)$, so it sets $f(8)=4$ to ‘use up’ both of these uncooperative numbers.

Comment: Your answer is better as it is more in depth and less ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest bijection, as you say, is $n \in \Bbb N \to 2n \in E^+$, but that doesn't respect the required values.  One easy way to fix that is just to permute the smallest values in some way.  As the largest required value is $16$, we can just permute the lowest $8$ values and leave everything above the same.  So $$f(n)=\begin {cases} 16&n=1\\12&n=2\\2&n=3\\4&n=4\\6&n=5\\8&n=6\\10&n=7\\14&n=8\\2n&n \gt 8 \end {cases}$$  You could use any other permutation for $4 \le n \le 8$ that you like.  You could also extend the explicit list if you want, but it would be more work.